# Owin middleware configuration in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am using self hosted Web API server with Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles  middleware for serving static files. Configuration:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    // Configure Web API for self-host. 
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    //...
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);

    var physicalFileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\Public");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalFileSystem.Root);
    var options = new FileServerOptions
    {
        FileSystem = physicalFileSystem,        
        RequestPath = PathString.FromUriComponent("/download")

    };
    appBuilder.UseFileServer(options);
}
```

How to get FileSystem setting (or path from where files are served) in WebAPI controller?

Comment: Why not just keep the path in a configuration setting somewhere and use that in your OWin config? You shouldn't have these "magic" strings in your code anyway.

Comment: You can't. That is the POINT of OWin. The Static File middle ware is independent of the WebAPI controller. Instead, you can have WebAPI host the static files. Just setup a route for a StaticFileController with a wildcard path, then parse the path in the controller to create a FileStream object to return.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem well, but if you want to pass any thing from middleware to another you can put it into environment object which is a dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string,object>
```

So if you want to pass any object from middleware to another use environment object.